# Showing that $|\cos x|+|\cos 2x|+\cdots+|\cos nx|\geq\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$, where $n\neq 2,4,6$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, inequality

For every natural number $n\neq 2,4,6$ and any real number $x$, prove the inequality:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n|\cos kx|=|\cos x|+\cdots+|\cos nx|\geq\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$$
My idea is that since the sum is concave in any interval where no $\cos kx$ changes sign, the minimum can only be obtained on points where some $\cos kx$ changes sign, namely on $x=\frac{p}{2k}\pi$ where $p$ is any integer such that $(p,2k)=1$ and $1\leq k\leq n$. When $2k\leq n$, namely the sum can cover $|\cos\frac{\pi}{2k}|+|\cos\frac{2\pi}{2k}|+\cdots+|\cos\frac{2k\pi}{2k}|=\cot\frac{\pi}{4k}$ for $\lfloor\frac{n}{2k}\rfloor$ times, it's easy to verify that the sum is greater than $\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$. But when $2k>n$, the sum become hard to manage for me.

Could anyone help me to complete this, or should I change my original idea?

**Update:** Now I've proved that $|\cos \frac{lp\pi}{2k}|\neq|\cos \frac{mp\pi}{2k}|$ when $ak\leq l<m<(a+1)k$ for some  integer $a$. So when $2k>n$ the problem can be converted to
$$\cos\frac{\pi}{2k}+\cdots+\cos\frac{k\pi}{2k}+\sin\frac{\pi}{2k}+\cdots+\sin\frac{(n-k)\pi}{2k}\\=\frac{1}{2}\cot\frac{\pi}{4k}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cot\frac{\pi}{4k}-\frac{\cos(\frac{(n-k)\pi}{2k}+\frac{\pi}{4k})}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{4k}}\geq\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor$$
which is a pure inequality problem I think. However, I can't solve it; could anyone help me with that?

Comment: This might be minor, but in the title, you have $|\cos{2x}|$ yet you say $n \neq 2$. Is that a typo?

Comment: I mean this inequality doesn't hold when $n=2,4,6$; for example $|\cos\frac{\pi}{4}|+|\cos\frac{2\pi}{4}|=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}<1=\lfloor\frac{2}{2}\rfloor$

Comment: My bad. I misread the proposal.

Comment: It would be sufficient to prove that the  global minimum is (except for $n=2,4,6$) at $x=\frac\pi2$.